# Quantum "First Passage" Time

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

My question first arose after reading *Quantum First Passage Time Problem - a Bohmian Perspective*, a great 9-page paper by Siddhant Das. I will first describe the problem and then display 3 different solutions to the problem.

**My question** is then the following: How are these solutions related to each other and how are they related to different QM interpretations (Bohmian, Copenhagen, etc.)?

**The problem:**
Consider a wave function $|\psi_0\rangle$ whose probability distribution is entirely (or almost entirely) contained in a ball of radius $d$ centered at the origin ($B_d(0)$). Additionally, assume the wave function evolves as a free particle. i.e.,

$i\hbar\partial_t|\psi_t\rangle = -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2|\psi_t\rangle$

If there is a spherical sensor with radius $d$ centered at the origin, what will be the probability distribution $\Pi(t)$ describing the probability that the sensor will announce the particle's "arrival" to the sphere at time $t$. The time that it takes for the sensor to go off is called the "first passage" time.

**Three Solutions:**

**1.** Outlined in Das's Paper

**2.** [Me] Define the joint probability distribution $|\psi_0(x)|^2\times|\psi_0(p)|^2$ on the phase space $\mathbb{R}^3\times\mathbb{R}^3$ (or $B_d(0)\times\mathbb{R}^3$). Then,

$\Pi(t) = \int_{\Omega_t} d(|\psi_0(x)|^2 \times |\psi_0(p)|^2) = \int_{\Omega_t} |\psi_0(x)|^2|\psi_0(p)|^2 d(x,p) = \int_{\Omega_t} |\psi_0(x)|^2|\psi_0(p)|^2d^3x \, d^3p$  ,

where $\Omega_t := \{ (x,p): x+tp \in \partial B_d(0) \}$. So the particle initially has a probability $|\psi_0(x)|^2|\psi_0(p)|^2$ of being in the phase state (x,p) and if $x+tp$ is on the sensor then the state (x,p) and its probability are accounted for in the probability of the particle hitting the sensor after $t$ units of time. This is because if the particle really were in the phase state $(x,p) \in \Omega_t$ then after $t$ units it would hit $\partial B_d(0)$, the sensor.

**3.**[Me] Define the quantity $$P(t) := \int_{\mathbb{R}^3- B_d(0)}|\psi_t(x)|^2d^3x\,\,\,.$$

Then, $\Pi(t) = \frac{dP(t)}{dt}$ seems reasonable. This is essentially the flux of the probability distribution through the sensor. More explicitly,

$\frac{dP(t)}{dt} = \int_{\mathbb{R}^3- B_d(0)}\frac{d}{dt}(\psi_t\psi_t^*)d^3x = \int_{\mathbb{R}^3- B_d(0)} \left(\frac{i\hbar}{2m}\psi_t^*\nabla\cdot\nabla\psi_t - \frac{i\hbar}{2m}\psi_t\nabla\cdot\nabla\psi_t^*\right)d^3x = \int_{\partial B_d(0)} \left(\frac{i\hbar}{2m}\psi_t^*\nabla\psi_t\cdot \mathbf{n} - \frac{i\hbar}{2m}\psi_t\nabla\psi_t^*\cdot\mathbf{n}\right)dS = \int_{\partial B_d(0)} \frac{i\hbar}{2m}\nabla|\psi_t(x)|^2 \cdot\mathbf{n}dS\,\,\,\,,$

with $\nabla|\psi_t(x)|^2$ and $\mathbf{n}$ both pointing inward.

This starts to resemble **2** once you plug in $|\psi_t(x)|^2 = \int_{\mathbb{R^3}}|\psi(p)|^2 (T_{(p,t)}\#|\psi_0(x)|^2)d^3p$, where $T_{(p,t)}\#|\psi_0(x)|^2 := |\psi_0(T_{(p,t)}^{-1}x)|^2$ is the pushforward of $\psi_0$ by $T_{(p,t)} : x \rightarrow x+tp$. But crucially, the difference between **2** and **3** is the projection onto the normal of sphere. The latter makes more sense to me because the sensor will probably be measuring the force normal to it.

Comment: Also, if anyone knows what the solution would look like in QFT formalism, that would be helpful too.

Comment: I think the question is clear, as someone familiar with this topic comparing approaches A, B, and C can be answered in one coherent message. I think it would not be necessary for OP to make separate questions for every combination AB, AC, and BC.